# Plaintiff and defendant have the same attributes

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2014

I am working on my final year project, "civil case management system" related to civil law.

I have a problem to store attributes for both plaintiff and defendant. They have the same attributes. I am not sure what is the best solution.

[image: image shows attributes both for plaintiff and defendant.]

Comment: @RandolphWest I don't know that I'd combine the two. Thinking ahead about indexing, awkward self joins, and table size.

Comment: @BillThor's answer is a perfect reason why my suggestion sucked. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As you are managing cases, you may want to ensure you don't double book people.  A person could be a Plaintiff on one case and Defendant on another.  I would have a persons table (legal persons like corporations can be problematic), and use a join table to associate persons with cases.  The join table would have a flag to indicate the role in the case.

This model could be extended to cover judges, lawyers, clerks etc.